# JFace: CheckboxTreeviewer with checkboxes for specific nodes

Tags: java, eclipse, checkbox, treeview, jface

I'm using a Jface CheckboxTreeViewer and wondering if it's possible to provide only specific nodes with checkboxes. I'm afraid that there is no native support and won't be easy to implement. Maybe someone cann help me with this.

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with `CheckboxTreeViewer`.

You can use `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider` to draw anything you like in a `TreeViewer`, so you could use that see http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html

For just check boxes you could just use the images returned by a normal label provider to show nothing / checked / unchecked.